# Illustrator 2019: how do I change default Placement Options to File Dimensions?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I finally found how to force Illustrator to respect the linked file's dimensions when modifying files outside of Illustrator by setting the `Placement Options` setting to `File Dimensions` (cf. screenshot below). However, I need to do this for every linked file, which is a pain.

How do I change the default behaviour? I want every image I drag-and-drop to be directly set to `Placement Options: File Dimensions`.

[image]